# convert json into data frame in R?

Tags: json, r

I need to convert json file into a data frame. Each line in the json file, may have different number of entries. For example

```
{"timestamp":"2016-12-13T04:04:06.394-0500",
"test101":"2016-12-13T04:04:06.382-0500",
"error":"false","from":"xon","event":"DAT","BT":"work","cd":"E","id":"IBM",
"key":"20161213040330617511","begin_work":"2016-12-13T04:04:06.383-0500"","@version:"1","@timestamp":"2016-12-14T20:04:29.502Z"}

{"timestamp":"2016-12-13T04:04:05.318-0500","test101":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.074-0500","error":"false","from":"de","event":"cp","BT":"work","cd":"dsh","id":"appl",
"key":"142314089",
"begin_work":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.074-0500",
"refresh":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.920-0500",
"co_refresh":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.769-0500",
"test104":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.832-0500",
"test104":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.832-0500",
"test105":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.031-0500",
"test7":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.032-0500",
"t-test9":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.704-0500",
"test10_StartDateTimeStamp":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.704-0500",
"stop":"2016-12-13T04:03:50.772-0500",
"stop_again":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.091-0500",
"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-12-14T20:04:29.503Z"}
{"timestamp":"2016-12-13T04:04:07.113-0500","test101":"2016-12-13T04:04:07.068-0500","error":"false","from":"xon","event":"DAT","BT":"work","cd":"E","id":"3YPS","key":"20161213040318326935","begin_work":"2016-12-13T04:04:07.069-0500","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-12-14T20:04:29.505Z"}
```

I need to start parsing the file form a keyword called "key" until a keyword called @version.

Data frame need to look something like this:

```
key group time
20161213040330617511 begin_work  2016-12-13T04:04:06.383-0500
142314089 begin_work 2016-12-13T04:03:46.074-0500
142314089 refresh 2016-12-13T04:03:45.920-0500
142314089 co_refresh 2016-12-13T04:03:45.769-0500
142314089 test104 2016-12-13T04:03:45.832-0500
```

etc

I have tried something like this:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table) 

setwd("C:/file/")

filenames <- list.files("system", pattern="*json*", full.names=TRUE)

dflist <- lapply(filenames, function(i) {
  jsonlite::fromJSON(
    paste0("[",
           paste0(readLines(i),collapse=","),
           "]"),flatten=TRUE
  )
})

d<-rbindlist(dflist, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

I need to put key value pairs into a 3 column data frame

I am getting field names after key as columns and NA as the values. Any ideas how could I convert json to df frame in R?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can try, a combination of dplyr and tidyr :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)

data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("data.json")
lapply(data, function(d) as_data_frame(d)) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  gather(groups, val, -timestamp, -key) %>% 
  select(key, group, timestamp)
```

BTW I had to change your json example a little bit.
Here's the json file I use:

```
{"x":{"timestamp":"2016-12-13T04:04:06.394-0500",
"test101":"2016-12-13T04:04:06.382-0500",
"error":"false","from":"xon","event":"DAT","BT":"work","cd":"E","id":"IBM",
"key":"20161213040330617511","begin_work":"2016-12-13T04:04:06.383-0500","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-12-14T20:04:29.502Z"},
"y":{"timestamp":"2016-12-13T04:04:05.318-0500","test101":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.074-0500","error":"false","from":"de","event":"cp","BT":"work","cd":"dsh","id":"appl",
"key":"142314089",
"begin_work":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.074-0500",
"refresh":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.920-0500",
"co_refresh":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.769-0500",
"test104":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.832-0500",
"test105":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.031-0500",
"test7":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.032-0500",
"t-test9":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.704-0500",
"test10_StartDateTimeStamp":"2016-12-13T04:03:45.704-0500",
"stop":"2016-12-13T04:03:50.772-0500",
"stop_again":"2016-12-13T04:03:46.091-0500",
"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-12-14T20:04:29.503Z"},
"z":{"timestamp":"2016-12-13T04:04:07.113-0500","test101":"2016-12-13T04:04:07.068-0500","error":"false","from":"xon","event":"DAT","BT":"work","cd":"E","id":"3YPS","key":"20161213040318326935","begin_work":"2016-12-13T04:04:07.069-0500","@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-12-14T20:04:29.505Z"}}
```

Comment: I get this error: data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(file)
Error: parse error: trailing garbage
          :"2016-12-14T20:04:29.500Z"} {"timestamp":"2016-12-13T04:04:
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: That's why I had to modify the json file, I'll edit my post so you can see the changes

Comment: I cannot change the json file. The actual file is huge. I need to be able read each line between { } and do the parsing.

Comment: when I use this: lapply(readLines(filename), fromJSON, flatten = TRUE), I get this error: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (flatten = TRUE)

Comment: also group is not a name in the json file, I need to create a column name in dataframe called group and put every key in the group column and value in the time frame column.

Comment: yes, the parameter `flatten` has been removed since then, you can just skip it.
For the group column, that's what the `gather` function is for.

Comment: I need to put values from key to @version to data frame format, columns names would be key, group and value. Each json line could have different number of key value pair. If it is easier, I just need the group and timestamp (key value pairs) in a data frame format).

Comment: I get this error: Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  time I change time to val, it is till not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130647/discussion-between-denrou-and-user1471980).

Comment: Because it should be `timestamp` in the select, not `time`

Comment: we're very close. It is picking up the timestamp at the begging of the line, I need it to pick up the value from the key value pair. I am in the chat room.